# Non-monotonic signal crossing VIL and VIH

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level

I'm using a logic buffer SN74LVC2G125 ([SN74LVC2G125 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc2g125.pdf?ts=1625708938399)) which is powered by 1.8V and has VIH and VIL of 1.17V and 0.63V, respectively.

If I have an input signal like below, could the buffer's output potentially toggle during time intervals B-C and E-F?
If not, what are potential negatives that can result from non-monotonic signals crossing VIH and VIL?

[image]

Comment: Am I reading this right that the input voltage is *negative*? You'll fry the chip; its absolute maximum limit on any input is no less than -0.5 volts.

Comment: @Hearth No, it's just a part of dashed line

Answer (score 1):

All that is guaranteed is that any voltage higher than \$V_{IH}\$ is interpreted as a high input, and any voltage lower than \$V_{IL}\$ is interpreted as a low input. All bets are off if \$V_{IL}<V_{in}<V_{IH}\$.

In all likelihood, there will be some voltage somewhere between \$V_{IL}\$ and \$V_{IH}\$ where the input toggles, but what that voltage is--or even whether that voltage is well defined--is not specified.

If you need the output to be in a well-defined state in this condition, you should use a Schmitt trigger. Lots of logic ICs are available with Schmitt trigger inputs, though I don't know if there's an equivalent to the 74xx125 with them. You could always use Schmitt inverters before your '125.